# Avoid ´ or ` characters on telephonic field

Tags: html, jquery, input, field

I have this input

```html
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputTelephone" placeholder="123-456-7890 Format" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" maxlength="12">
```

And have this jQuery code

```js
$(function () {

    $('#inputTelephone').keydown(function (e) {
     var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
     $text = $(this); 
     if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
         if($text.val().indexOf('´') === 1){
            $text.val($text.val().replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''));
         }
         if ($text.val().length === 3) {
             $text.val($text.val() + '-');
         }
         if ($text.val().length === 7) {
             $text.val($text.val() + '-');
         }
     }

     return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
 })
});
```

So far works flawless but when I type "´" or "`" it is shown

I saw on this link that here works properly (no accent characters shown)

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745

I'll better put the code that works on that link

```
(function($, undefined) {

  "use strict";

  // When ready.
  $(function() {
    
    var $form = $( "#form" );
    var $input = $form.find( "input" );

    $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {
      
      
      // When user select text in the document, also abort.
      var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
      if ( selection !== '' ) {
        return;
      }
      
      // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
      if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
        return;
      }
      
      
      var $this = $( this );
      
      // Get the value.
      var input = $this.val();
      
      var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
          input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;

          $this.val( function() {
            return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "en-US" );
          } );
    } );
    
    /**
     * ==================================
     * When Form Submitted
     * ==================================
     */
    $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
      
      var $this = $( this );
      var arr = $this.serializeArray();
    
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); // Sanitize the values.
      };
      
      console.log( arr );
      
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But I´m kind of missplaced here, is there any way to avoid such behavior so the field only allows numbers?

Comment: But your code block characters  **´** and **`**. So what do you mean?

Comment: I correct, it does block ´or ` but also blocks the dashes (-) but I need the dashes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by setting up the right RegEx on this line

```
$text.val($text.val().replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ""));
```